# Different behaviors of CascadingParameter and ChildContent to create indented Child components in Blazor

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am about to create an indented Parent/child component in which I can go deeper and deeper like having a child and then a grandchild and so on. The question is I am getting different behaviours between using the `ChildContent` and `CascadingParameter` . On `ChildContent` I have the correct order of indented child components. but the `CascadingParameter` goes to the first level of childs first and then goes deeper and deeper.
I have provided the full code and its output to make it more clear.

So the questions are:

1. How we can explain the difference of these two approaches?
2. How can I get the list of indented child components and defien the depth level of a child component (to be consumed in the code; not in the razor)?

Here's the Code:
Parent (SwitchContentControl.razor)

```
    <CascadingValue Value="this">
    <ul>
        @ChildContent
    </ul>
    <p>
        @* The list of childs *@
        @string.Join(',', MenuItems.Select(x => x.Text))
    </p>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    public List<SwitchMenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; } = new List<SwitchMenuItem>();

    internal void AddItem(SwitchMenuItem menuItem)
    {
        MenuItems.Add(menuItem);
    }
}
```

Child (SwitchMenuItem.razor)

```
<li>
    @ChildContent
</li>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private SwitchMenuControl Parent { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (Parent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Parent), "MenuItem component must exist within a MenuControl");
        Parent.AddItem(this);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

And This how I call this component on my Index.razor

```
<SwitchMenuControl>
    <SwitchMenuItem Text="menu 1">
        <h1>The first Menu</h1>
        <SwitchMenuItem Text="menu 1-1">
            <h1>The first Menu 1-1</h1>
            <SwitchMenuItem Text="menu 1-1-1">
                <h1>The first Menu 1-1-1</h1>
            </SwitchMenuItem>
            <SwitchMenuItem Text="menu 1-1-2">
                <h1>The first Menu 1-1-2</h1>
            </SwitchMenuItem>
        </SwitchMenuItem>
        <SwitchMenuItem Text="menu 1-2">
            <h1>The first Menu 1-2</h1>
        </SwitchMenuItem>
        <SwitchMenuItem Text="menu 1-3">
            <h1>The first Menu 1-3</h1>
        </SwitchMenuItem>
    </SwitchMenuItem>
    <SwitchMenuItem Text="menu 2" >
        <h1>The second Menu</h1>
    </SwitchMenuItem>
    <SwitchMenuItem Text="menu 3" >
        <h1>The third Menu</h1>
    </SwitchMenuItem>
    <SwitchMenuItem Text="menu 4">
        <h1>The fourth Menu</h1>
        <SwitchMenuItem Text="menu 4-1">
            <h1>The fourth Menu 4-1</h1>
        </SwitchMenuItem>
        <SwitchMenuItem Text="menu 4-2">
            <h1>The fourth Menu 4-2</h1>
        </SwitchMenuItem>
    </SwitchMenuItem>
</SwitchMenuControl>
```

Now the output us like this. Note the difference between `ChildContent` and the `CascadingParameter`'s list:

```
SwitchMenuControl
The first Menu
The first Menu 1-1
The first Menu 1-1-1
The first Menu 1-1-2
The first Menu 1-2
The first Menu 1-3
The second Menu
The third Menu
The fourth Menu
The fourth Menu 4-1
The fourth Menu 4-2
menu 1,menu 2,menu 3,menu 4,menu 1-1,menu 1-2,menu 1-3,menu 4-1,menu 4-2,menu 1-1-1,menu 1-1-2
```

Comment: They are apples and oranges - don't expect component initialization to tell you anything about depth. Each SwitchMenuItem should cascade itself down to it's children - and the children can request the "Depth" from their parent. (parent depth+1)

Comment: Hey @MisterMagoo , Thanks for the reply. I know they go with different approaches and this is exactly what I need to understand. I couldn't find the GitHub code behind these things to understand them better, so I came up asking here. although it's not clear for me how is it possible to get the depth of a child from its parents?

Comment: The source for blazor is in https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore  - An example of depth aware component https://blazorfiddle.com/s/wk4lwqnb